# Simple Tree Traversal in Python: Help me debug

Tags: python, recursion, binary-tree

This is how I would traverse a binary tree in Python

```
def binary_tree(root):
  if root.left:
    binary_tree(root.left)
  print root
  if root.right:
    binary_tree(root.right)
```

if I need to return the traversed path:

```
def binary_tree(node, path):
  if root.left:
    binary_tree(root.left)
  path.append(root)
  if root.right:
    binary_tree(root.right)
  return path
```

Okay, easy enough. I am confident in tree traversals, so I try the following.

```
def nary_tree(root, value):
    """return True if there is a node with value exists in root"""
    if not root: #empty tree
        return False
    if root.left:
        nary_tree(root.left, value)
    if root.data == value: #recurse up until the current node has a right child
        return True
    if root.right:
        nary_tree(root.right, value)
    return False
```

This does not return True when it should. So I try to debug, stepping into the function. I realize that I am not supposed to escape a recursion just by returning a value. The above code will return `True` once and `False` many times, in case there is a matching node, and I will almost always get a `False`. So I try the following:

```
def nary_tree(root, value):
    """return True if there is a node with value exists in root"""
    if not root: #empty tree
        return False
    if root.left:
        return nary_tree(root.left, value)
    if root.data == value:
        #but in this case, this is never executed
        return True 
    if root.right:
        return nary_tree(root.right, value)
    return False #how was this being executed in above example then?
```

**Questions:**

1. What am I misunderstanding?
2. How would you fix the above code?

I have been fairly comfortable at writing recursive functions, but I seem to be still confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if the current node has the data, if it has a left node, you are returning from the function. Ideally, this should have been like this

```
def nary_tree(root, value):
    """return True if there is a node with value exists in root"""
    if not root: #empty tree
        return False
    if root.data == value:
        return True 
    if nary_tree(root.left, value):
        return True
    if nary_tree(root.right, value):
        return True
    return False #how was this being executed in above example then?
```

Comment: How does if nary_tree(root.left, value) actually work in this case?

Comment: @MaximusS If that returns `True`, statements inside `if` will be executed.